# Locale::acceptFromHttp not working correctly

Tags: php, locale, php-7

I am working on a Laravel project and got an empty string the following code.

```
<?php
    use Locale;

    $locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
    // or $locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
    echo $locale;
```

The result should be `en-US`, but returns empty string. I could confirm the request header on my Google Chrome browser v95.

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Then I guess the header doesn’t contain a parseable locale string. It’s difficult to help without knowing _what_ the value of the header you’re testing with is.

Comment: @Martin Bean I just confirm there is Accept-Language value via chrome inspection. I guess it might be browse problem. But I can't exam it on older browsers.

Comment: `Locale::acceptFromHttp('en-US,en;q=0.9')` returns `en_US` for me. Check that `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` contains what you expect.

Comment: @Devstorm21 I didn’t ask if there _was_ an `Accept-Language` header; I said it’s difficult to help without knowing the _value_ of that header.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] is 'en-US,en;q=0.9'

Comment: What does your code output if you hard-code the value in, i.e. `echo Locale::acceptFromHttp('en-US,en;q=0.9')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the error out to edit `c:\xampp\php\php.ini`.
and enable `"extension=php_intl.dll"`.